# Request from Twitter to get User details

Tags: apex, integration

I got an access token from Twitter using client id and client secret. Now i want the user details from Twitter like userid, profile_image_url etc using the access token. What should be the request to be sent to Twitter? I need a proper request format

Thanks

Comment: you shd chk twitter api docs https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public or post this question in twitter dev forums https://twittercommunity.com/

Comment: @VamsiKrishna yeah i checked the docs but the proper request format is not specified there

Comment: What is the problem with this? : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Shailesh%20Patil

Comment: @ShaileshPatil I dont have the screen_name. I just have access token. Is it possible with that?